# Track how many time video is play in website using firebase analytics for react js

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, event-handling, firebase-analytics, video-tracking

i am trying to track video information in firebase analytics for react js.

In firebase analytics option is not showing and also event also not generating.

Comment: Did you try logging a custom event for this? If so, and it is not working, could you provide how you're logging the events. Also, could you verify if it shows in DebugVIew?

Comment: yes , I want to generate custom event to count video views. can anyone please provide steps for that.

Answer (score 0):

To log custom event in Analytics, you might want to try something like this:

```
<Button
 title="Play Video"
 onPress={async () =>
   await analytics().logEvent('play_video', {
     id: 3745092,
   })
 }
/>
```

To test your events, you could use the Analytics [debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enable_debug_mode) in your browser, install the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) Chrome extension.